# Interface-less view at EJB 3.1

Tags: proxy, ejb, java, ejb-3.1

Basically I have 2 questions.

1. What EJB 3.1 spec says about interface-less EJB bean? Why it was introduced so late?
2. What is typical and/or reference implementation? AFAIK, it is impossible to implement it with JDK dynamic proxy, because no interface is available. It is possible however to define dynamic proxy with Javaassist or CGLIB, but I doubt that this implementation can be reference one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your second question answers your first one.
It is much easier to implement container for interface-full beans because interface based dynamic proxys are supported by JDK. It is however annoying for application developer to create interface every time he has to create bean. This was the reason to introduce interface-less beans. However implementation of container that supports such beans requires byte code engineering technique your mentioned that is much harder taking in consideration multi-class loading environment, dynamic re-deployment and other issues. This probably was the reason that interface-less EJBs were not introduced earlier.